# Cannot copy database from Asset folder in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, assets

I have a database that I created in SQLite Browser. It has so far 34 tables and I am also planning to use ORMLite to do database insert, delete etc. 
My problem is, since I created the database offline, I will have to ship the database with the app. So I kept my database in the assets folder and then I tried to copy the database.
Going through other stackoverflow posts made me to use [this code](https://gist.github.com/donaldlittlepie/1271795). I call this class from my MainActivity so that whenever user is inside my app, I can check if my database is there or not. But things aren't working as expected. Here is the logcat output [link](http://pastebin.com/LWvqHLD3). It shows that it can't find my database file in the assets. Or I may be wrong. Please help! Thanks!

Relevant Codes in MainActivity.java

```java
AssetDatabaseOpenHelper adb = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = adb.openDatabase();
    if(db.isOpen())
    {
        System.out.println("Database open, now closing");
        db.close();
    }
```

Relevant Codes in AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java.

```java
 private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb.db";
 public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    System.out.println(dbFile.toString());
    //File databasefile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"databases");
    //System.out.println(databasefile.toString());
    if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        try {
            //databasefile.mkdir();
            copyDatabase(dbFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
        }
    }

    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer);
    }

    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

Logcat:

```
11-08 16:24:03.773: E/Trace(5937): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 16:28:32.524: E/Copy Error(7319): Copy may have been aborted
11-08 16:30:17.233: E/Trace(7890): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 16:30:18.213: E/Copy Error(7890): Copy may have been aborted
11-08 16:32:57.994: E/Trace(8751): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 16:32:58.773: E/Copy Error(8751): Copy may have been aborted
11-08 16:42:46.534: E/Trace(11771): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.[packagename ommitted]/com.[packagename ommitted].MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating source database
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating source database
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at [packagename ommitted].db.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:29)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at [packagename ommitted].MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    ... 11 more
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/[packagename ommitted]/databases/mydb.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at [packagename ommitted].db.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.copyDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:38)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at [packagename ommitted].db.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:27)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    ... 15 more
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
11-08 16:42:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(11771):    ... 19 more
11-08 16:45:36.693: E/Trace(12662): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[packagename ommitted]/[packagename ommitted].MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating source database
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating source database
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at [packagename ommitted].db.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:29)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at [packagename ommitted].MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    ... 11 more
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/[packagename ommitted]/databases/mydb.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at [packagename ommitted].db.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.copyDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:38)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at [packagename ommitted].db.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:27)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    ... 15 more
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
11-08 16:45:37.293: E/AndroidRuntime(12662):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: You should make sure that the database path exists. I assume you are trying to copy the database into a non-existing directory.

Comment: Please post the used code here. There is no reasin to give a link as the amount of code will be pretty small. Also post the logcat here. You did not tell where you want to copy the database file to.

Comment: @Robert You assumption seems to be true. If I manually create the folder "databases" inside data/data/package-name/ from the File Explorer, the database copy is a success. However, I cannot do that from my program, that is create the directory first. Tried mkdir() doesn't work.

Comment: @greenapps I have shared a github link, thats the code I am referring to. The very same code points to the place where I want to copy the file. context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME) points to /data/data/package-name'/databases/database-name

Comment: It seems as if i have to repeat my requests.

Comment: @greenapps question edited. let me know if this what you are asking for.

Comment: You only fullfilled one request. Please fullfill the other too. What is the value of DB_NAME and what is the name of the file you put in assets?

Comment: @greenapps Name of the file in the assets is "mydb.db". If I manually create the folder "databases" inside data/data/package-name/ from the File Explorer, the code works.

Comment: `/data/data/[packagename ommitted]/databases` I think the databases dir not yet exists. So check if it exists and create it before you try to put a file in it.

Comment: @greenapps YEAH! Robert figured that out early, and I replied in the comments what I did next and whats wrong currently. Can you add anything new? or you still have pending requests to get served?

Comment: Sorry I oversaw that. Yes Robert was spot on. But mkdir() should work. So show the used code please. I think that `DB_NAME = "mydb.db";` should be `DB_NAME = "mydb";`. And if you use it for assets you have to add the ".db" there. Check twice please what `System.out.println(dbFile.toString());` is printing.

Comment: inside public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() in the question, I have commented out some codes that I tried for mkdir(). Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: If `File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);` is the file "/data/data/[packagename ommitted]/databases/mydb.db" Then you should check that "/data/data/[packagename ommitted]/databases" exists. And if not create it. You can use `if ( ! dbFile.getParentFile().exists() ) dbFile.getParentFile().mkdir();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that the database path exists.

I assume you are trying to copy the database into a non-existing directory, because the error message is "No such file or directory" on the line where you create the FileOutputStream in copyDatabase().

Comment: This error has appeared on me to. When you "clear data" and "Uninstall app" android deletes "/data/data/<your_package>/databases" directory. Therefore you absolutely has to create "database" dir by `if ( ! dbFile.getParentFile().exists() ) dbFile.getParentFile().mkdir();` as @greenapps said. Thanks to @Robert and @greenapps